# Calling a method of a foreign object from a parameter (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec, weakly-typed

Everyone,

I'm working on an assignment for a class I'm taking at university this year and we're supposed to make an implementation of a graph in Ruby.  This is my first experience with Ruby in this setting, so I'm having a hard time with the whole weakly typed aspect of it.

I'm trying to have each vertex store the edges incident to it like

```
def new_edge v1, v2, *lv                                                      
    edge = MyEdge.new *lv
    v1.incident_edges.push(edge)
    v2.incident_edges.push(edge)
    return edge 
end
```

So, this method takes two vertexes and an optional name as parameters.  I also have `attr_accessor :incident_edges` in the MyVertex class.

The problem is that when I try to run it with rspec, I get `undefined method     incident_edges' for nil:NilClass, which makes sense since Ruby doesn't know what type the object is.  My question is if there is a way to get this to work or should I just use an adjacency matrix for this?

Comment: "which makes sense since Ruby doesn't know what type the object is" - no, you are getting the error because `v1` is `nil`. Nothing to do with weak typing, you would get the same thing in strongly-typed Java (`NullPointerException`). You need to make sure the arguments you are passing to `new_edge` are defined.

Comment: What Amadan said is true. Either v1 or v2 are nil. Ruby doesn't care what type of object it is and it doesn't have to know. It calls method incident_edges on object v1 which is nil so it doesn't have method incident_edges defined.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks!  I was trying to use an object that I had declared earlier in my rspec.describe statement, but it was no longer valid.